# Lightweight desktop environments

Tags: desktop-environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What different desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)
>   [light weight window manager/desktop environment like unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95889/light-weight-window-manager-desktop-environment-like-unity)

Hi I was thinking about try a lightweight desktop for my Ubuntu.

I like Unity but am just curious to see how well they work.

But I don't know where to start, theres L and X Ubuntu, whats the difference's between the two ?, I read X is not very lightweight and L is very ugly.

My PC is of reasonable spec so which distro's are not just for underpowered machines ?

Can any one suggest any others to try ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enlightenment is pretty fast. It's also extremely customizable, and potentially good looking. Might not be what you are looking for, but I think it deserves more attention. I am also trying out xfce at the moment. So far, I am very satisfied, but there are some bugs I have to sort out before it's usable.

Last time I tried lubuntu, it was not nearly good enough for everyday, or non-geek usage. I frequently had to retreat to command line to do stuff. I like their intentions, though, but I wouldn't recommend it for everyday use unless you've got a really slow computer or until they sort out some of the issues.

Answer (score 4):

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) is a lightweight derivative of Ubuntu that using the LXDE desktop environment. You can install it as a desktop environment on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

See [this link](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-install-the-lubuntu-desktop) for more detail.