# What's the lightest Ubuntu desktop environment?

Tags: hardware, desktop-environments, compatibility

My computer has 1GB ram and a very end low graphics card, but I don't know how much power it has.

Unity is very slow on my computer, and I saw that there are many desktop environments which are much lighter and faster, even for a slow computer.

So, what's the lightest desktop environment?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Definitely [Lxde](http://lxde.org/)
or [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org/).

First remove Unity with this command (make a backup before proceeding for safety!):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge unity unity-common unity-services unity-lens-\* unity-scope-\* unity-webapps-\* gnome-control-center-unity hud libunity-core-6\* libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps\* appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt\* overlay-scrollbar\* activity-log-manager-control-center firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu libufe-xidgetter0 xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-websites-integration gnome-control-center gnome-session
```

then:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/thunderbird-addons/extensions/messagingmenu@mozilla.com.xpi
```

Now, to install Lxde run this command:

`sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

or for Xfce this one:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Lastly, reboot and enjoy!

Hope this helped you.

Comment: I would advise to use `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` instead, to have all the leightweight programs Xfce designed (like Mousepad, etc.)

Comment: @MrVaykadji edited.

Comment: `lubuntu-desktop` also exists. They are metapackages that will install all the "suite" Canonical partners (xfce-ubuntu team and lxde-ubuntu team) recommend.

Comment: @MrVaykadji done.

Comment: Lxde is lighter than Xfce, tested and approved!

Comment: I hate how xfce looks, but it's like its name is just designed for left-hand typing and it sounds so smooth in my brain that I keep writing it everywhere, my debug variables, empty self-email messages etc.

Comment: Lubuntu . . . but if you could put another gig of memory, you'd be happier.

Comment: Actually XFCE is not really a light DE. It averages only about 10% lighter than Cinnamon whereas MATE is 40% lighter than XFCE. http://l3net.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/a-memory-comparison-of-light-linux-desktops-part-3/

Comment: I would suggest installing the other desktop environment before removing unity, as it removes unity's default network manager.

Comment: If you do remove your desktop environment before installing a new DE and find your network is out you can run something like this from terminal.
sudo ip link set dev eth0 down
sudo dhclient eth0
You'll get an IP address through DHCP and be able to access the network again and run apt-get.

Comment: I thought swapping out unity for Xubuntu desktop was a great idea @slowbanned , but alas it didn't work, help, help.  Many errors, "Failed to fetch"  etc. suggested try fix-missing or sudo apt-get.  Couldn't seem to get anything to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you think it is recommended to uninstall unity? You can install any other environment without removing it

Comment: These aren't the lightest desktop environments. Consider at least fluxbox or openbox.

Answer (score 24):

The *real* answer is: ***NO*** Desktop Environment.

Depending on what you want to do, running shell only might be a decent choice.

You can use something like `fbterm` to split your screen into multiple sections

[image]

And there are shell programs that allow you to surf the web, view PDFs and play music as well.

*Disclaimer*: That *isn't* my desktop screenshot, My shell only laptop is a work in progress, however I know someone who has successfully set this up, so I know what I'm talking about.

*Disclaimer 2*: I don't think the shell web browsers play well with Stack Exchange.

Comment: Regarding disclaimer 2: on stackapps.com there is a shell-only stackexchange client.

Comment: To have no graphical environment at all is insufficient for the vast majority of desktop users.  Looking at pictures of cats and other typical pastimes are greatly restricted.

Comment: @11684 that is good to know!

Comment: @gerrit you're right, I stand corrected.

Comment: @gerrit I'm sure, there is an ASCII-art front-end, built entirely on  for the hardcore unix fans who enjoy the occasional kitty pic!

Comment: I dont think it is an appropiate answer for this question, but upvoting! Will make my server management tasks easier

Comment: there are some tools you can't use in non-desktop enviroment, like, netbeans, eclipse, mysqladminitrator, etc etc

Answer (score 20):

As other users have answered, LXDE is the lightest option. My input, however, would be that it definitely makes sense to do a clean install of lubuntu as a whole OS, replacing your ubuntu system.

The lubuntu OS comes packaged with many lightweight programs that maximize efficiency (though you can still install all of your heavier favorites because lubuntu uses the same software sources as regular ubuntu), has very little bloatware, and the entire system is built from the ground up specifically to be lightweight. Also, many of the applications it comes with integrate very well with LXDE specifically. I think that this is the best way to get the most out of low-spec machines.

You can download it [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) and use unetbootin to make a live CD or flash drive.

Comment: Why does it make better sense to do a clean install?

Answer (score 9):

There are two major Desktop Enviroments that you could describe as lightweight.

First of all there is Xfce is used by [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) and there is LXDE which is used by [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

LXDE seems to be a little faster than Xfce but this little boost costs a lot of functionality. Xfce is also really fast but with more functionality.

There are probably more and better Desktop Enviroments for your purpose but these are the major ones.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the lightest options, I personally love [Openbox](http://openbox.org/wiki/Main_Page) or [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/)!

Check out [Crunchbang Linux](http://www.crunchbanglinux.org/) which uses Openbox as it's default. I have it running on my netbook like a champ!

Comment: No doubt that these are lightweight window managers. But the OP asked for complete Desktop Environments.

Comment: [Fluxbuntu](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=Fluxbuntu) was very promising; shame it was discontinued.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Lxde. For optimal performance install the Lubuntu from the minimal media. You can download it from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall

Answer (score 3):

LXDE is the lightest, though Xbuntu is close and is better looking imo.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered widely in the forum;
Why not try Lightweight-XDE Ubuntu (Lubuntu) ?

Also have a look at these posts:

[Lightweight desktop environments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185061/lightweight-desktop-environments?rq=1)
or
[lightweight window manager/desktop environment similar to Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95889/lightweight-window-manager-desktop-environment-similar-to-unity)

In each of them you can see lots of suggested/related posts in the right corner of the page.

Comment: I think Lubuntu is for Lxde Ubuntu, not Light^^