# Why is Ubuntu 14.04 so slow?

Tags: 14.04

I have a Dell Dimension E510, with nothing on the disk but 14.04. However, it is running very slow. I don't know why, 11.10 and 12.04 ran fine.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: I have a similar Dell and had to switch out the original video card for one that worked better with Unity. You might look particularly at the video card AND the amount of system RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research I just did, the Dell Dimension E510 is a slightly older machine initially intended for Windows XP.  (I looked at CNET's specs on the Dell Dimension E510 Home.)  Even though it has more than enough RAM and other specs to run Ubuntu 14.04, I typically suggest to friends that if they're finding a Linux solution for a computer designed to run XP, it's better to go with an older Ubuntu, lighter Ubuntu, or another Linux distro altogether.  Just because a device has enough to run an OS, does not mean that the device has enough to run it smoothly.  You may also want to try lxde (lubuntu) or xfce (xubuntu) instead of running the Ubuntu based off Unity.  [What's the lightest Ubuntu desktop environment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413569/whats-the-lightest-ubuntu-desktop-environment) can help you with that.

Comment: Thanks! @Colonel I will try this and let you know how it works.