# Ram Ubuntu 18.04, clean RAM

Tags: 18.04, ram

Can you tell me how to clean RAM on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. My laptop almost full RAM when working, But when i closed applications, and nothing running, RAM not reduced. Why and how to resolved? 
Thanks for your help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve ram usage excessive on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134523/how-to-solve-ram-usage-excessive-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts)

Comment: @steeldriver no no. I want to ask about clean ram. Because, when i restart system, ram usage when no app using is about 1G. And after work, it is 2,7G or more than. i think can clean ram dont need restart. Do you know it?

Comment: RAM is certainly used by applications. But it's also used as a file/disk cache. So RAM usage will always be higher after the system has been running for a while. Quite normal. No need to "clean" RAM.

Comment: @heynnema i know that. But on Ubuntu 16.04 not like that. After work and close all apps, ram is about 1,5G. it is okay. Ubuntu 18.04 so excessive. So I think clean ram will be ok for system.

Comment: If you **were** able to clean RAM, you'd be clearing out disk/file cache, and your performance would get **worse**, not better. Leave it alone.