# 20 old Dell Latitudes donated to our school

Tags: system-installation

Each of the laptops has 2 GB and is currently running Windows XP (well, limping along).

Any suggestions for using ubuntu?

(I'm a novice!)

Thanks!

Comment: Here you'll find a way: [lightweight window manager/desktop environment similar to Unity](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95889/lightweight-window-manager-desktop-environment-similar-to-unity)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on a Dell Latitude D630 with 2GB (same configuration you have). I am happy with the performance. I also run Ubuntu on both of my desktops, and find the laptop performance almost as good..

I recommend the LTS (Long Term Support) Ubuntu releases, so you won't have upgrade them as often.

Comment: Sounds good.  But, I'm having trouble with that download.  The file ends in <.ios.part> and nothing recognizes it when I try to burn a dvd....

Comment: "That download"? Generally download tools use the "`.part`" extension for incomplete portions of the download.  It looks like the download failed. Try again, and watch for success/failure. You should get a `.iso` file that your DVD burner will recognize.

Comment: Switched over to xubuntu and have successfully installed it on the D600 Latitude.  But have lost the wireless driver?  Any suggestions as to how to get the wireless working again?

Comment: Yes. Ask a new question. Asking additional questions in comments is bad because: 1) It makes it impossible for Other People to find the Q&A; 2) It leads to a conversation in comments (which are not what comments are for) and deprives me (and other answerers) of the formatting tools available in the Answer field.